# Hashing and HMAC gives different output in Python and JS

Tags: javascript, python, cryptojs, hashlib, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to convert a python code That encode a string With HMAC into JS using Crypto JS. But the HMAC string produced in the python and JS COde is different.

Python code

`

```
import hashlib, json, hmac, secrets

date = "2024-01-16 16:11:11"
nonce = 'ksjdnf5646512'
data = {key:value}
method = 'PATCH'
api = 'api'
content_type = 'application/json'
    
hashed_data = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')).digest()
string_to_hash = f"{method}\n{date}\n{api}\n{content_type}\n{nonce}\n{hashed_data}"
hmac_string = str(hmac.new('secretkey'.encode('utf-8'), string_to_hash.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest())

print(json.dumps(data))
print(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
print(hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')))
print(string_to_hash)
print(hashed_data)
print(hmac_string)
```

JS Code

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
date = "2024-01-16 16:11:11"
nonce = 'ksjdnf5646512'
data = {key: value}
method = 'PATCH'
api = 'api'
content_type = 'application/json'
data = JSON.stringify(data)
hashed_data = CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(data))
const string_to_hash = `${method}\n${date}\n${api}\n${content_type}\n${nonce}\n${hashed_data}`;
const hmacString = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(string_to_hash), CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('secretkey')))
console.log(hmacString)
```

The HMAC string produced in both codes are different.I need it to be same.

I tried using different encryptions in Crypto JS. I cannot chenge the python code. I can write the JS code as i want. I thik the issue might be due to difference in libraries in python and js

Comment: I need the both hmac string to be same.

Comment: This is the output of python code:                 {key: value}
b'{key: value}'
<sha256 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x7fb0141ef7d0>
PATCH
2024-01-16 16:11:11
api
application/json
ksjdnf5646512
b'W\x94+\xd2\x90\x0bbe2\\\xf7\x9f;\xe58\x1a\x12\t\xc0\xaf\x0e\xb1\x07Q\xc1e\x8a\xd3\x15|\xaf\xc2'
b'W\x94+\xd2\x90\x0bbe2\\\xf7\x9f;\xe58\x1a\x12\t\xc0\xaf\x0e\xb1\x07Q\xc1e\x8a\xd3\x15|\xaf\xc2'
63d556cbc1982f505352187f11231a93182c3dddd6a9f6a2d316e46acf8ead05

Comment: This is the output of JS code: 15e818ada447f2893f8276ad847802cacbffd880d5c61bcddb172f071260c425

Comment: The last one printed is the hmac string i need to get with the JS code. But hmac string produced my JS code is different from 63d556cbc1982f505352187f11231a93182c3dddd6a9f6a2d316e46acf8ead05 .

Comment: also i have changed api and data which produced this hmac string for security reasons

Comment: No i have changed it. It could be anything but when i gave the same thing in the JS code I am getting different hmac string

Comment: oh sorry. data = {'agent_last_ping_time': "2024-1-16 12:45:23"}  . You can take this one

Comment: All the extra information should be posted in the question, not in the comments. Please edit the question and delete the comments.

Comment: The fact that you can't change the pythin is a problem, since the pythin is producing JSON with space after the `:`

Comment: you'll probably have to convert your JSON by `.replaceAll(":", ": ").replaceAll(",", ", ")` ... of course, there is no guarantee of object property order, so, you're probably going to have more issues than that

Comment: of course, you have `:` in the data, so that won't work either

Comment: In addition to the JSON issue (which is most efficiently solved with a JSON canonicalization), the implicit conversion of the bytes-like object `hashed_data` into a string during concatenation generally leads to different strings in both codes, which in turn results in different HMACs, even with identical JSON strings.

Answer (score 1):

When I set `data = {'hello': 100}` using both Python and JS, I got the following:

```
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"hello": 100}'
```

```
> JSON.stringify(data)
'{"hello":100}'
```

These are not identical strings.  Therefore you should not expect them to give you identical results when you run `hmac`.  As already noted above, you should only hmac a string for which you know its exact format.

Comment: Okay that is a difference . But when i initialise the data in js with the same string as python , Still not getting the same hmac string from python